# Euler method for ODE with noisy derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations, eulers-method

I am interested in numerically integrating a noisy differential equation:
$\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,t) + \epsilon(t)$ where $\epsilon(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Is this a RODE or SODE?

How does this relate to numerically integrating $\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,t)$ using Euler and adding Gaussian noise after each step?

Comment: This is nothing, it is not defined. On the one hand a random function as described is too irregular to do anything with it. On the other, it is too small, its contributions become increasingly smaller with declining step size. It was found long ago that the correct size requires the square root of the step size. A sensible realization of this are SDE with increments of Brownian motions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you! What do you mean by "correct size"?

Comment: If you set $x(t+δt)=x(t)+f(t,x(t))δt+(μ+σz(t))δt$, you will find that on average over $N$ steps where $Δt=Nδt$ is still small against the variation speed of $f$ or the solution of $\dot x=f(t,x)$, the random terms will sum up to approximately $x(t+Δt)=x(t)+f(t,x(t))Δt+(μ+σδt\,Z(t)) Δt$ with a $Z(t)\sim N(0,1)$ a related but different random function. So in your equation what the random term means depends on a step size that is not actually part of the equation. There is a reason for the introduction of the Ito calculus.